# Servicestack async method (v4)

Tags: asynchronous, methods, servicestack

at this moment I am developing an android db access to  a servicestack web api.

I need to show a message of "wait please..." when the user interacts with the db, I read some documentation:

[Calling from client side an async method](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile)

But I cannot found how the async method must be implemented in the webapi, serverside.

Can you please share a link to the documentation? or a simple working sample?

I have this before trying to convert it to an async call.

```
var response = jsonClient.Send(new UsuarioLogin { Cuenta = txtCuenta.Text, P = txtPass.Text});
```

After some read, the latter code is converted into this:

```
var response = await jsonClient.SendAsync(new UsuarioLogin { Cuenta = txtCuenta.Text, P = txtPass.Text});
```

So, in the server side I have this(just an extract):

```
        public object Post(UsuarioLogin request)
    {
        var _usuario = usuarioRepo.Login(_cuenta, _password);
        if (_usuario != null)
        {
            if (_usuario.UsuarioPerfilId != 2 ) 
            {
                return new UsuarioLoginResponse { Ret = -3 }; 
            }
```

How can I convert it to an async method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side and client-side async are opaque and unrelated, i.e. an async call on the client works the same way irrespective if it's calling a sync or an async service, there's also no difference for sync client either. Essentially how the server is implemented has no effect on how it's called on the client.

To make an async service on the Server you just need to return a `Task`, you can look at the [AsyncTaskTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b0c980381804877dfaed2378c71b56cbde580e48/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AsyncTaskTests.cs#L254) for different examples of how to create an async Service.

There are a lot of benefits for making non-blocking async calls on the client since this can be called from the UI thread without blocking the UI. But there's less value of server-side async which adds a lot of hidden artificial complexity, is [easy to deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), requires rewriting I/O operations to be async and in many cases wont improve performance unless I/O is the bottleneck, e.g. async doesn't help when [calling a single RDBMS](https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/522928496583409664). You're going to get a lot more performance benefits from using [Caching](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) instead.